# Clearing sessionStorage is not clearing the session storage from the iFrame. Is there a way for this to be done?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session, iframe

I am currently running a web app that is essentially a menu with a group of buttons. When you press a button it hides the menu and displays an iFrame behind.

I am wanting to clear a session when I navigate away from that iFrame, I have tried doing :

```
clearSession() {
 try {
     window.sessionStorage.clear()
     }
 catch(err) {
       console.log(err)
     }
}
```

However, this is only clearing the session of my application and not of the iFrame (the iFrame session is the shu.ac.uk). Is it possible to clear the session of the iFrame?

I can see both my session and the iFrame session in the browser:

[image: Session Storage in Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have reference to the window object of your iframe not only your parent page.

```js
const iframe = document.queryselector('iframe');
iframe.contentWindow.sessionStorage.clear();
```